# How do I get flexbox to auto size?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to build a dynamic flexbox that will fill if there is a missing column.

What I currently have is `row1` and `row2` which are `70%` and allow for the column. But when there's no column, it's just empty.

[image]

I would like `row1` and `row2` to stretch if there is no column present:

Code

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
}

.c {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

.a, .b {
  background: green;
  height: 45px;
  width: 70%;
}

.a {
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="a">row1</div>
<div class="b">row2</div>
<div class="c">column</div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="a">row1</div>
<div class="b">row2</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If instead of `width` you use `min-width`, you don't constrain the columns when there's no sidebar:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
}

.c {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

.a, .b {
  background: green;
  height: 45px;
  min-width: 70%;
}

.a {
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="a">row1</div>
  <div class="b">row2</div>
  <div class="c">column</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="a">row1</div>
  <div class="b">row2</div>
</section>
```